# Correct sum with multiple subrecords (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, sum

This have maybe been asked several times before, but I do not how to achieve a correct som from both parent and child.

Here is the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE co
    (coid int4, coname text);    
INSERT INTO co
    (coid, coname)
VALUES
    (1, 'Volvo'),
    (2, 'Ford'),
    (3, 'Jeep'),
    (4, 'Toyota')

;

CREATE TABLE inv
    (invid int4, invco int4, invsum numeric(10,2));
INSERT INTO inv
    (invid, invco, invsum)
VALUES
    (1,1,100),
    (2,1,100),
    (3,2,100),
    (4,3,100),
    (5,4,100)
;

CREATE TABLE po
    (poid int4, poinv int4, posum int4);
INSERT INTO po
    (poid, poinv, posum)
VALUES
    (1,1,50),
    (2,1,50),
    (3,3,100),
    (4,4,100)
;
```

I started with this simple query

```
SELECT    coname, sum(invsum)
FROM      inv
LEFT JOIN co ON coid=invco
GROUP BY  1
ORDER BY  1
```

Which gave a correct result:

```
coname     sum
Ford       100
Jeep       100
Toyota     100 
Volvo      200
```

Then I added the po record and the sums became incorrect:

```
SELECT    coname, sum(posum) as po, sum(invsum)
FROM      inv
LEFT JOIN co ON coid=invco
LEFT JOIN po ON poinv=invid
GROUP BY  1
ORDER BY  1
```

Which multiplied the sum for Volvo:

```
coname    po     sum
Ford      100    100
Jeep      100    100
Toyota    (null) 100 (no records for po = correct)
Volvo     100    300 (wrong sum for inv)
```

How do I construct a query that gives correct result with multiple subrecords of po? (Window function?)

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d90c/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation *before* the joins.  This is a little complicated in your case, because the relationship between `co` and `po` seems to require `inv`:

```
SELECT co.coname, p.posum, i.invsum
FROM co LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.invco, sum(i.invsum) as invsum
      FROM inv i
      GROUP BY i.invco
     ) i
     ON co.coid = i.invco LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.invco, sum(po.posum) as posum
      FROM po JOIN
           inv i
           ON po.poinv = i.invid
      GROUP BY i.invco
     ) p
     ON co.coid = p.invco
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note:  I presume the logic is to keep everything in the `co` table, even if there are no matches in the other tables.  The `LEFT JOIN` should start with this table, the one with all the rows you want to keep.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? `co` seems to be just a dictionary table for `inv.invco`, so shouldn't you start with `inv`?

Comment: I want to make a list of invoices with sums. I suppose this will give all companies even those without invoices?

Comment: @sibert change first LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN. Gordon, I've corrected an alias in your query.

Comment: Does not help. There will be thousands of companies that will have no invoices. They will have (null) values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab645/1

Comment: @sibert . . . If you only want companies that have invoices, then use an inner join instead of a left join.

Comment: Thank you! It works as it should, but is there any other way to achieve this?