# Join data from three related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

In Postgres I have the following 4 tables

```
user (
id,
name

);
order(
id,
user_id
)
service(
id,
name

);
order_to_service(
id,
order_id,
service_id
price
);
```

I want to write a query to see User name , amount of orders of this user and how much money he spend on all orders
Example:

```
name   amount  price
Albert   100    3200
```

This is my query

```
select u.name , count(o.user_id),sum(ots.price)
from orders o inner join users u on u.id=o.user_id
inner join order_to_service ots on ots.order_id = o.id

where(o.user_id is not null) group by u.name
```

This is my result:

```
"Аlbert";55;29978
```

Accodring to this result user with name Albert has 55 orders
But using this query

```
select count(*) from orders where user_id = (select id from users where name like 'Albert')
Result is 33
```

What's wrong with my first query?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558439/correct-sum-with-multiple-subrecords-postgresql

Comment: I think you are counting users from the order and then in the where condition you are check for not null o.user_id is not null instead check for name albert then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship between Orders table and Order_to_service table is one to many, then you would need to sum up the price per order in Order_to_service table before joining with the Orders table.  Try this:

```
select u.name , count(o.user_id),sum(ots.price_tot)  
from orders o inner join users u on u.id=o.user_id  
inner join ( select order_id, sum(price) as price_tot  
             from order_to_service    
             group by order_id ) ots   
          on ots.order_id = o.id  
where (o.user_id is not null) group by u.name
```